# Jasmine throws error (SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word)

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am working on an Angular2 project where I am using Jasmine to perform some small unit test tasks. For that, I have the below code:

```
import {HomeComponent} from "./home.component";

describe("A suite is just a function", function() {
var a;

it("and so is a spec", function() {
 a = true;

randomNumber(30).toBe(true);
});
});
```

However, on the terminal it throws the below error:

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import 
{HomeComponent} from "./home.component";
                                                          ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word
at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
```

It seems that it has an issue when I use `import` to import a component.

How can I solve that?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the first line with import. You're not using `HomeComponent` in your test. If you do need to use it, declare it properly using `TestBed`, e.g.

```
import {HomeComponent} from "./home.component";
beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ HomeComponent]
      ...
    })
  });
```